# ActiveRecord: retrieving existing entity in different sessions

Tags: c#, nhibernate, activerecord

I'm using Castle ActiveRecord 3.0 and I have a problem with object references when fetching them from the database. When I'm fetching multiple entities within the same SessionScope I get the same object references for related entities.

But often i can't use the same session scope to fetch all the objects I need. It's kinda hard to describe it so here's an example:

```
[ActiveRecord(Table = "car")]
public class Car : ActiveRecordLinqBase<Car>
{
    [PrimaryKey("id")]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    [OneToOne(PropertyRef = "Car", Cascade = CascadeEnum.SaveUpdate)]
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
}

[ActiveRecord("location")]
public class Location : ActiveRecordLinqBase<Location>
{
    [PrimaryKey(Column = "id")]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    [BelongsTo("car_id", NotFoundBehaviour = NotFoundBehaviour.Ignore, 
                Cascade = CascadeEnum.SaveUpdate)]
    public virtual Car Car { get; set; }
}

[ActiveRecord(Table = "move_order")]
public class MoveOrder : ActiveRecordLinqBase<MoveOrder>
{
    [PrimaryKey(Column = "id")]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    [BelongsTo(Column = "car_id")]
    public virtual Car Car { get; set; }

    [BelongsTo(Column = "destination_id")]
    public virtual Location Destination { get; set; }
}
```

I'm creating some objects to start with:

```
using (new SessionScope())
{
    var car = new Car() { };
    var initialLocation = new Location() { Car = car };
    initialLocation.Save();
    var destinationLocation = new Location();
    destinationLocation.Save();
}
```

Then if I create 2 move orders for the same Car/Location it works just fine:

```
MoveOrder moveOrder;
MoveOrder moveOrder2;
using (new SessionScope())
{
    moveOrder = new MoveOrder()
        {
            Destination = Location.Queryable.First(x => x.Car == null),
            Car = Car.Queryable.First(); 
        };
    moveOrder2 = new MoveOrder()
        {
            Destination = Location.Queryable.First(x => x.Car == null),
            Car = Car.Queryable.First()
        };
}
```

Object references are equal for:

- moveOrder.Car, moveOrder2.Car
- moveOrder.Location, moveOrder2.Location

But when the I use different session scopes to get both MoveOrders:

```
using (new SessionScope())
{
    moveOrder = new MoveOrder()
    {
        Destination = Location.Queryable.First(x => x.Car == null),
        Car = Car.Queryable.First()
    };
}
```

and

```
using (new SessionScope())
{
    moveOrder2 = new MoveOrder()
    {
        Destination = Location.Queryable.First(x => x.Car == null),
        Car = Car.Queryable.First()
    };
}
```

None of those properties are reference equal, but logically those are the same entities.
I also tried with getting Nhibernate session and associating all detached objects back into new session:

```
using (var sess = GetSession())
{
    sess.Lock(moveOrder.Destination, LockMode.Read);
    sess.Lock(moveOrder.Car, LockMode.Read);

    moveOrder2 = new MoveOrder()
    {
        Destination = sess.Get<Location>(moveOrder.Destination.Id),
        Car = sess.Get<Car>(moveOrder.Car.Id),
    };
}
```

This does the trick in this case, but has some issues:

- I have to pass EVERY database entity I currently use to the new session
- I cannot use queries, session.Get works for Ids

The main question is:

**How can I achieve getting the same object references from DB every time I fetch the same entities (same Ids)?**

Also tried to use Nhibernate second level cache by configuring it in AR init and adding `Cache = CacheEnum.ReadWrite` to every db class ActiveRecord attribute - with no result.

I'd rather not keep the same session open all time.